# Parsing Json Array In Ajax Response

Tags: javascript, json

I am working with an application that makes an ajax call and gets a json response. The response is shown below:

```
    "msg":"successful.","data":{"fee":"100","balance":{"0":"12180"},"status":{"0":"0"}}
```

The code application logic tests for the value of the "status" field and checks if it is zero before populating a textbox with the response.

The issue is that the "status" field is not being accessed correctly..(i believe) therefore the condition to display the response is never true.

The code is :

```
   if(data_array.data.status == 0) {/// do stuff
```

I am of the opinion that this method of accessing the status field is wrong..

I tried this

```
   if(data_array.data.status.0 == 0) {///
```

but i am getting an error....
should i try..

```
    data_array.data.status[0]==0...
```

How can i access the "status" field value?

Thanks

Comment: try this: data_array.data.status["0"]==0

Comment: Is there a reason status is `{"0":"0"}`? Makes more sense for it to be `"status": "0"`. Then you can access it like you wanted to, data_array.data.status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you parse the JSON string? If not, try the following:

```
jsonStr = '{"msg":"successful.","data":{"fee":"100","balance":
{"0":"12180"},"status":{"0":"0"}}}';

jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
status = jsonObj.data.status[0];
if(status == 0) { 
    // do some code 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY:

```
   var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(e);
   var status = obj.status["0"];
```

Answer (score 0):

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

The error has doesn't have to do with accessing the field improperly (although you should be using `[0]` or `["0"]`).
Surround your JSON with curly braces `{}` and it will fix the parsing error.

```js
var obj = {"msg": "successful.","data":{"fee": "100","balance":{"0": "12180"},"status":{"0":"0"}}};
```

```html
<button onclick="alert(obj.data.status[0]);">Click me!</button>
```